# Simulate input in c++ and read it in JAVA?

Tags: java, c++, linux

I'm facing a problem here and i'm thinking you guys might be able to help/point me toward appropriate documentation.

But first, context:

I'm working on this c++ script that can call and run different java runnables with arguments. But I'm a complete noob in c++, and in general coding. Started Java a couple weeks back.

this c++ script has for purpose (among other things) to intercept inputs and simulate other inputs that will then be read by already running java threads. The goal is for java to be able to run a loop like this:

```
public class CalledByCpp extends JFrame{
    protected static KeyList listener = new KeyList(); //custom KeyListener

    //frame constructor goes here

    public void main(String[] args){
        //initialization of bunch of things

        this.addKeyListener(listener);
        while(true){
            requestFocus();
        }
    }

    protected static class KeyList(){
        //Handling of key pressed
    }
```

Does this sounds possible? Or is there an easier method? And what's the event creation method i'm looking for in c++?

Side note: Both cpp and java would run on a Linux desktop (debian) without any screen attached so I assume it's safe for the java frame to loop on requestFocus(). Right?

Another lead I had was to build a driver, but I have no idea what's the difference, and how to do that, or even if it's a lead worth investing time and effort into when this cpp could act as a driver itself.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since you're a self-proclaimed "noob" and are referring to C++ code as a `script`, you should *definitely* not mix languages.  What you're doing is fairly complicated, but it can probably be done in Java alone.  Adding C++ to the mix is likely to cause nothing but problems for you.

Comment: Yes I figured, the problem is that my c++ runnable (is that the word you would use?) HAS to be in c++. It does other things that can't be done in java. At this point I don't have a choice: it has to be a C++ runnable "simulating" inputs and java runnables "listening" to those inputs.

Comment: What do you mean you don't have a choice? Is it a school project or something? You *always* have a choice. In fact, making an optimal choice (well...at least a *good* choice) is probably the most important thing you can do in software development. Consider that it doesn't matter how fast a runner you are if you tie 50lb cinder blocks to your legs before the race starts. Mixing two languages where you barely know one and definitely don't know the other will almost certainly have this effect.

Comment: I understand the easiest choice would be to do all in java, and that I would be able to without a problem. However the conditions on the inputs to simulate use a pre-compiled c++ library.  All I need really a link to the documentation explaining how to simulate a user input in c++, if this is possible at all. I'm confident on how to handle the rest. Maybe I'm unreasonable or I'm explaining myself poorly, I don't know. Sorry if it's the case.

Comment: @Yogso I have posted some code in my updated answer covering the basics of the UNIX C library that you can use. Basically, it lets you launch Java from C++ and gives you a way to write data to stdin of Java.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to give the input to Java through standard in. The 'event' to listen for could just be reading a line from standard in, or possibly multiple lines. You would just need to have some way of detecting when to stop reading and do something. Since all threads in your Java program would receive this data, you would also need some way of detecting which thread was intended to use that data. I would start your C++ program first, and then launch Java from within your C++ program, set up so that you can write data into standard in of the Java process from the C++ program. In a UNIX environment, there is a standard way to do this. From your C++ program, run something like the following (you will need to include the header `unistd.h`):

```
int fd[2];

// For sharing data with Java process
pipe(fd);

pid_t id = fork();

if (id < 0) {// system error
    printf("Failed to fork process");
    exit(1);
}
// parent process
else if (id > 0) {// id of child process (Java)
    // optional: writes to standard out go to Java process
    // can also use write(fd[1], <data>, <length>)
    dup2(1, fd[1]);

    close(fd[0]);

    // do stuff and write to Java process as needed

    // signal end of data to Java process
    close(fd[1]);

    // wait for Java process to exit and clean it up
    if (wait(NULL) < 0) {// system error
        exit(2);
    }
}
else {// child (Java) process, id = 0
    // Read stdin from parent (C++) process
    dup2(0, fd[0]);

    close(fd[1]);

    char* path = "/path/to/java";
    // Arguments to java. Always end with NULL
    char* argv[] = {"Java_arg1", "Java_arg2", NULL}

    // Run java
    if (execv(path, argv) < 0) {// system error
        printf("Failed to execute java command");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however there's nothing I can do: I have to simulate the inputs in c++. I would not be mixing language per se, rather I would have one C++ running and simulating inputs on a system level, and java reading those "user input".

Comment: @user4581301 Now it is an answer. @Yogso Can't really be more complete unless I know how your Java program is organized. That will change what arguments you pass to `java`. For example, if you had compiled your code into a jar file, then you would pass `"-jar"` and `"/path/to/jar"`.

Comment: Definitely an answer now. Not sure it answers the asker's question, sounds like the asker wants to simulate keyboard inputs to a GUI. Without that constraint I'd write something like what you've done.

Comment: thank you for this updated answer @HackerBoss. Like user4581301 said, it's not really what I'm looking for since there's no actual input simulated. But I do understand why others adviced against mixing languages. 

If I understand your code correctly, multiple "input simulation" would cause a queue in my java program to process, and that's really counter productive. I wasn't clear to begin with, i'll try to make a diagram explaining how things are expected to work when I have time tomorrow.

However I *might* have found what I'm looking for with Xdotool, but I am not able to test today.

Answer (score 0):

So I've had the time to try out a quick code. Using Xdotool, which you can find on github or apt-get install xdotool

```
//in the loop deciding which input to simulate
system("xdotool key T");
```

this would simulate one press of the key T. No console popping up, the script can run in background and generate inputs easily. They are actual system input so I've been able to read them in java.